# How to change base url?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am not sure the title of the question is correct,  but I'll try to explain what I need.

We host multiple web applications on a single machine, so

`https://localhost:8080`

and

`https://localhost:8081`

point to different applications.

Meanwhile, API gateway maps request without dropping the URL suffix:

`https://api.domain.com/service1/Home/Index`

turns into

`https://localhost:8080/service1/Home/Index`

and

`https://api.domain.com/service2/Home/Index`

into

`https://localhost:8081/service2/Home/Index`

I would like the app's root `~` to resolve to `hostUrl+suffix` where suffix is a configured value.

I used this [blogpost](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/06/global-route-prefix-with-asp-net-core-mvc-revisited/) to globally prefix all the routes for controllers and pages, but now I struggle with static files.

I am able to virtually move `wwwroot`:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    RequestPath = $"/{GlobalPrefix}"
});
```

but `<link href="~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />` does not contain `GlobalPrefix` part when rendered.

So I would like to add this `GlobalPrefix` to whatever base URL site is hosted at. Be it a self-hosted app or in IIS.

P.S. [RTFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2) =)

Comment: Have you tried setting up the path base using app.UsePathBase("/myPath") in Configure? There have been changes in ASP.NET Core 2 regarding that (https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/226). Also, be aware of a strange behavior: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/893

Comment: @Daboul, thanks, it works. Was looking for something similar among `WebHostBuilder` extensions =)

Comment: Good to hear. I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `app.UsePathBase("/myPath")`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is working in that case.

There have been changes in ASP.NET Core 2 regarding that (http://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/226). Also, be aware of a strange behavior: http://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/893